# Is attempting to steal a crime in Canada?

Tags: canada, theft

If someone attempted to steal something from a company and then was caught in the process and never actually got to steal the item, is that punishable by law in Canada? The company is in the U.S. the would-be theif is a Canadian resident.

Comment: Are you saying that the company and the (potential) crime are in the US, or the company is US based but in Canada?

Comment: The company is US based but they sell their products online and can ship to Canada. A Canadian based "customer" was sending fake photos of a product he claimed he purchased from the company so that he could get another one sent to him as a replacement, for free, through warranty. Thus attempting to steal, but not succeeding as the company realized the photos were fraudulent. Had they not realized the photos were fake, they would have sent him a product for free under the impression that they were replacing a faulty product he'd purchased, but he'd never purchased that product.

Comment: A bit tricky to determine which countries law would apply. The action happened in Canada, the effect would have happened in the USA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Canadian law, attempted fraud such as this would be covered under section 660 of the Criminal Code (R.S.C., 1985, c. C-46). Yes, it is punishable.

https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-46/section-660.html

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate it, this is great